# issue with double/reverse quotes in su - user -c command

Tags: command-line, quoting, su

I'm trying to execute this command but getting error due to double, single, reverse quotes.

```
su - ctmagent -c "/usr/ctmagent/ctm/exe/ctmpsm -UPDATEAJF `/usr/ctmagent/ctm/exe/ctmpsm -LISTJOB NOTOK | grep -w TESTJ | awk -F"|" '{print $1}'` RERUN"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes inside double quotes.
Try replacing the double quotes in `awk -F"|"` with single quotes.

Comment: Removing the quotes and escaping the pipe with backslash should work, too `-F\|`